# Am trying to install wine but this is the error am getting. What might be the problem?

Tags: python, wine

E: Unsupported file /root/.wine/drive_c/Python27/python.exe given on commandline

Answer (score 1):

try to run linux version of python beside using windows version
you can try to install like this
https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/linux/